# Firefox add ones problem Installation aborted because the add-on appears to be corrupt

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

i have made some [Firefox add ones](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/ss-sci-hub) from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967148/script-to-find-where-is-sci-hub-now-maybe-google-result-address-scraper) by this [git hub source-code](https://github.com/elasa-Sites/Side-Auto_Sci-Hub):

[image]

but when those updated into Firefox extension server it shown this error:

> Installation aborted because the add-on appears to be corrupt.
>
> This is not a public listing. You are only seeing it because of
>   elevated permissions.

like this:

[image]

my Firefox version:

[image]

So i asked is there any online tester to test the source files to check why this problem happened?

thanks.

Comment: I have updated git hub repo by git command from my local repo and it has been solved by delay, so i dont know the source was form time delay needed or repo updating.

Comment: I just uploaded a new addon as well and I'm getting the same error as well. I guess I'll just wait until mozilla has looked at it.